# Part-time freelancing in Ireland along with full time job on CSEP

Tags: ireland, freelance

I am working full time in Ireland for an Irish employer. I am a non-EEA national and I have a Stamp 1 based visa on the CSEP which my employer applied and got for me. Am I allowed to freelance for foreign clients on the side on weekends along with my full time job in my current immigration condition?